# How to make an SQL insert statement with foreign keys generated at time of statement

Tags: sql

My Database layout with tables Head, Child, Tail:

```
Head
    Head_Id
    Name

Child
    Child_Id
    Head_Id
    Child_Name
Tail
    Tail_Id
    Child_Id
    Tail_Name
```

Head_Id, Child_Id, and Tail_Id are all auto incrementing indexers, and Head_id is a foreign key same with Child_Id, which I linked to the proper key in myphpadmin.  Now, how would I insert a piece of data such that

```
Head = "a"
    child-1 = "b"
        tail-1 = "d"
        tail-2 = "e"
    child-2 = "c"
        Tail-1 = "f"
        tail-2 = "g"
```

So that all foreign keys are properly linked.  Is this possible with 1 SQL statement ? If so, how so?

Comment: no - each table is a separate insert statement.  you may reference CURRVAL and NEXTVAL for the sequence numbers if this is Oracle in a PLSQL block..

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.